# Unity ARKit automatically positions terrain on startup

Tags: ios, iphone, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, arkit

I just started learning ARKit with Unity. I've downloaded SDK from Asset store, imported it, opened demo scene and added a terrain. I've added it under HitCubeParent as a child:

http://shrani.si/f/40/UP/1q7QqoFl/1/capture.jpg

I've added a Unity AR Hit Test Example Script on a terrain and linked HitCubeParent to it:

http://shrani.si/f/6/133/3w5sasQA/1/capture1.jpg

When I build a game on iPhone, ARKit is working, but one thing that bothers me is that terrain is positioned automatically when scene starts (even though i don't tap on the screen). It causes bad positioning like terrain floating in the air or similar issues. I would like to modify the kit so when the scene starts, only generated blue plane is visible. User should then adjust the position of a plane to a table or similar flat surface and tap on the screen to position the terrain on that plane.

Like this:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OCzuNnejwy4

Any good tutorials on this ? I've searched a lot but couldn't find anything usefull.

Answer (score 1):

Disable the Terrain and enable it after the first successful ARHitTestResult. See line 68 in UnityARHitTestExample.cs:

```
if (HitTestWithResultType (point, resultType))
{
    return;
}
```

This is actually confusing since this HitTest method actually positions the m_HitTransform and is not merely a test.
In this if block you could enable your terrain, after you disabled it in the Awake method.